# Color in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print in terminal with colors using python ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

hello guys
did i can do like C#  in console?
to make

```
print 'hello'
```

write hello with green color and

```
print 'WOW am sexy'
```

write it with red color?

Answer (score 2):

Previously:

- **[Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)**
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor
- http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.can_change_color
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 1):

[colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)